# laravel 5.2 set attribute name

Tags: php, laravel-5

How i set custom the attributte names in laravel 5.2 I already try this code, but doesn't work:

```
$attNames = array(
        'code' => 'Número',
        'contributor' => 'Nº Contribuinte',
        'create_date' => 'Data criação',
        'address' => 'Morada',
        'zip_code' => 'Cod. Postal',
        'city' => 'Localidade',
        'email' => 'E-mail',
        'phone_number' => 'Telefone',
        'note' => 'Observações',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($client, $this->rules,[],$attNames);
    $validator->setAttributeNames($attNames); 
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        // send back to the page with the input data and errors
        $errors = $validator->messages();
        return Redirect::to('/client/create')->withInput()->withErrors($errors);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have passed wrong arguments to **Validator::make**.

You can pass only three arguments.

As per [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation),

> If needed, you may use custom error messages for validation instead of
>   the defaults. There are several ways to specify custom messages.
>   First, you may pass the custom messages as the third argument to the
>   **Validator::make** method.

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

Comment: I already try :
$validator = Validator::make($client, $this->rules, $attNames);
but e doesn't translate the attributte

Comment: For language translation, you should see this link:- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/localization

Comment: the error message is:O campo code é obrigatório. instead O campo Número é obrigatório. he doesn't replace the attribute name 'code' for the atrriutte 'Número'

Answer (score 0):

I figure out.
controller:

```
use Validator;
(...)
$attName=array(
            'code' => trans('validation.code'),
            'contributor' => trans('validation.contributor'),
            'create_date' => trans('validation.create_date'),
            'address' => trans('validation.address'),
            'zip_code' => trans('validation.zip_code'),
            'city' => trans('validation.city'),
            'email' => trans('validation.email'),
            'phone_number' => trans('validation.phone_number'),
            'note' => trans('validation.note'),
        );
 $validator = Validator::make($client, $this->rules, [], $attNames);
```

validation.php:

```
'attributes' => [
    'code' => 'número',
    'contributor' => 'nº contribuinte',
    'create_date' => 'data criação',
    'address' => 'morada',
    'zip_code' => 'cod. postal',
    'city' => 'localidade',
    'email' => 'e-mail',
    'phone_number' => 'telefone',
    'note' => 'observações',
],
```